# How to get Android volley request header?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to get the request headers sent to server from Android volley request.
I can find webView headers as below

```
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2 ...
X-re ...
```

But I can't find the volley request header structure to be manipulated by web server. Please help.

I can't find nothing from

```
VolleyRequest.getHeaders()  //output => {}
```